# No directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" angular 6

Tags: forms, pug, angular6

I'm trying to validate a form with angular 6.
Here's my PUG code:-

```
.form-group
  input.input-lg.form-control(type="text", 
    placeholder="Your firstname",
    name="fname",
    #fname="ngModel", 
    required)
    .alert.alert-danger(*ngIf="fname.invalid")
    p([hidden]="!fname.errors.required") First name is required`
```

and I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: There is no directive with
>   "exportAs" set to "ngModel" ("         ]#fname="ngModel" required="required"/>

I've already imported the FormsModule in the app.module.ts.

Answer (score 0):

I had a simmilar problem which I asked about in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52654903/angular-4-6-code-error-there-is-no-directive-with-exportas-set-to-ngmodel?noredirect=1#comment92241273_52654903). Check the comment section. My problem was that i forgot to add the `imports: [FormsModule, ...` in the app.module.ts. Maybe this is your problem too.