# Angular 4 -> 6 code error "There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel""

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-forms, ngmodel

So, i bought [Mosh's Angular 4 course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5E2AVpwsko) not knowing that it is Angular 4 and the latest is Angular 6.

Yea, I've heared that the difference between 4 and 6 is small in terms of coding, but hear me out.

In one of the lectures about template driven forms, he uses this code:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
      <input             <-- WE ARE LOOKING AT THIS ELEMENT
        ngModel
        name="firstName"
        id="firstName"
        type="text"
        class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="comment">Comment</label>
    <textarea id="comment" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

So i repeat that in Angular I installed (later I've found out that he's using 4 and I have installed 6), and it works fine.

Now, he wants to show what `ngModel` looks like by printing the `ngModel` object to the console, so he creates a variable and logs it by adding `log(msg) { console.log(msg); }` to the `.ts` file, and now the `<intput>` mentioned above looks like this:

```
<input 
    ngModel
    name="firstName"
    #firstName="ngModel"         <-- ADDED
    (change)="log(firstName)"    <-- ADDED
    id="firstName"
    type="text"
    class="form-control" />
```

So he compiles it, it works, the console logs the `ngModel` just fine.
So then I compile the same code, and I get this:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" ("
        ngModel
        name="firstName"
        [ERROR ->]#firstName="ngModel"
        (change)="log(firstName)"
        id="firstName"
"): ng:///AppModule/ContactFormComponent.html@6:8
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:1021)
    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:14830)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:24018)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:24005)
    at compiler.js:23948
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:23948)
    at compiler.js:23858
    at Object.then (compiler.js:1012)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:23857)
```

So, offcorse, I google to find why is this happening, and then I see [this question on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52027573/no-directive-with-exportas-set-to-ngmodel-angular-6) and see that it has no answers. I am now here, hoping someone will come and tell me "you poor soul, you have a typo" or something.

**NOTE 1** I hope I'm not breaking any laws by quoting the lectures I paid for from mr Mosh. If so, please note me, I will remove this question. Also, i sincerely reccomend his course. 10/10.

**NOTE 2** Please have in mind the question I stumbled upon that was not answered at the time I am posting this question. My is a bit more detailed, so I wouldn't say it is a duplicate, but it would be nice that that question gets answered too.

**QUSETION** If not clear by now: what does `There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel"` mean, and how do I fix it? What are the crutial differences between Angular 4 and 6 that make the code from A4 invalid in A6?

I am tottaly new to angular btw.

Comment: Did you add `FormsModule` to your `AppModule`'s `imports` array?

Comment: Guess I didnt... but now that I did, like this: `import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';` and `declarations: [ FormsModule, ...` and now I get error `Unexpected module 'FormsModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.`

Comment: I said add it to `imports` array and **NOT** `declarations` array.

Comment: @SiddAjmera my saviour